# Can we consider Linked List to be a Skewed Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, tree, language-agnostic

Considering a Skewed tree, it has all the nodes only a particular direction (left or right). Can we say that a Linked List with n-nodes is also a Skewed tree with height n ?

Comment: You could say it's a very special case of a tree, but why would you want to?  If your data structure has only one link in each node, then you can't really use it as a tree, but you could convert it to one.  Without context, your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. A list is a degenerate tree. You could call it a "maximally unbalanced tree" if you want.

In fact, that's exactly what someone means when they say that you need to balance a binary search tree in order to get the O(log n) lookup performance, because if your tree becomes unbalanced, it degenerates into a list and lookup performance becomes O(n).

It is also sometimes useful to think in the other direction: most people have no trouble at all understanding how a persistent list works, but many people have trouble understanding how a persistent tree works. But the thing is: it actually works exactly like a persistent list, and it's generally easy to understand how a persistent tree works, if you start from a persistent list and then re-interpret that list as a degenerate tree.

Comment: `maximally unbalanced tree`, so can we deduce a rule, that says "any linked list is a tree, but not every tree is a linked list" (i.e. any tree with more than one branches is not a linked list) ?